# Learn only non-zero elements in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

For a project, I want to have connections only with specific number of neurons instead of a fully connected layer. To achieve this I created a mask-like weight initialization where I set the unwanted connections to 0, by using matmul I can achieve my goal, but the problem that I have right now is that I want these connections to not participate in the learning process as well(e.g., the zero connections remain zero and do not get in the way of learning of non-zero elements). Any suggestions for how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by manually resetting gradients before applying them. Replace the usual optimization operation, like:

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

with manual gradient computation and applying:

```
grads = tf.gradients(loss, ['name-of-your-neurons-variable'])
#  ... here put code for gradient resetting using the mask
grads_and_vars = list(zip(grads, ['name-of-your-neurons-variable']))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5)
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)
```

Comment: Thanks, did you try out the second part? I get this error when I specify the variables for 'name-of-your-neurons-variable' I only want one w to be trained not all of the network
`NotImplementedError: ('Trying to update a Tensor ', <tf.Tensor 'mul:0' shape=(2560, 256) dtype=float32>)`

Comment: I think I found out what to do, I have to remove ['name-of-your-neurons-variable'] and with something like grads_and_vars = [(grads[6][0],grads[6][1])] get the exact weights that I want to use.

Comment: No, I haven't tried. If I had a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) than I would probably be able to give more concrete answer. For now, I could give only some direction where to move.